# youtube-dl Downloading channel page #number => how to skip old pages?

Tags: youtube-dl

I live off grid, no internet access. Once in a while I go to the library and run my scripts, which backs up video channels (youtube, bitchute, rumble, ...)

I lose a lot of time with large channels... because youtube-dl has to load all the pages... like:

> [BitChuteChannel] thedavidknightshow: Downloading channel page 1
> ...
>  [BitChuteChannel] thedavidknightshow: Downloading channel page
> 194

The library blocks BitChute and rumble... so I have to torify those, which slows it down even more.

Since I have already downloaded the whole channel, how do I index the latest page(s) only?

Other tips to speed up the process are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the oldest files you can use `--playlist-items` or `--playlist-end`

For example:

```
yt-dlp playlist_url --playlist-end 30
```

Will only fetch the latest 1 or 2 pages. This also works on accounts or channels because channels are basically playlists of a specific kind

Answer (score 0):

The --playlist-end thing might work, but you have two other pretty good options.  The first option is when you are downloading use the

```
--download-archive <archive file>
```

option.  You give it a filename like YOUTUBE.CHANNEL.archive.txt and it will list the files downloaded in that archive file.  The next time you run the command, say a couple months later, it will skip files you have already downloaded.

The other option is

```
--datebefore YYYYMMDD
```

and

```
--dateafter YYYYMMDD
```

You can use --datebefore to download everything from the beginning up until a certain date.  You can use --dateafter to download everything from that date until the current date.  For example if I stopped watching a show around november and didnt want to download anything after that, I could use

```
--datebefore 20231101
```

So an example of the entire command line would be something like this

```
yt-dlp -f 'bv*[height<=1440]+ba' --embed-thumbnail --embed-metadata --download-archive YOUTUBE.CHANNEL.archive.txt https://www.youtube.com/@YOUTUBE.CHANNEL/videos --datebefore 20231101 -o '%(channel)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

Replace YOUTUBE.CHANNEL with whatever the correct name is.  That should solve your problem.